# Nagios contacts configuration

Tags: nagios, nagiosxi

I am new at learning the Nagios of 4.4.6 version. I have configured `host configuration` and `service configuration` in my Nagios CLI and restarted then everything updated on Nagios Web GUI (localhost/nagiosxi).

When I was updating "contact" in web GUI, it is updating on Nagios CLI of `/usr/local/nagios/etc/contacts.cfg`. But when I was configured my own "contact" in `/usr/local/nagios/etc/contacts.cfg` it has not been updating on web GUI.

Comment: Did you restart after adding the contact ?

Comment: yes, I have checked the configurations and restarted, but not updating on web GUI

Comment: It’s difficult to say without seeing , can you share the command you used for reloading the nagios

Comment: "sudo /usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios -v usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg" and "systemctl restart nagios"

Comment: Try reloading the config `/etc/rc.d/init.d/nagios reload`

Comment: In my machine there is no such file it is showing "-bash: /etc/rc.d/init.d/nagios: No such file or directory"

Comment: `/etc/init.d/nagios` ?

Comment: No such file "/etc/init.d/nagios"

Comment: `systemctl reload nagios`?

Comment: I have tried "systemctl reload nagios" , but did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy existing `/usr/local/nagios/etc/contacts.cfg` into `/usr/local/nagios/etc/import`. Change anything, add anything, then do "Apply Configuration". The file will be removed from the import folder, all new contacs will appear in contacts.cfg. All changes will also be applied. However, you cannot remove contacts using this procedure.

If you make any mistake in the cfg file, the existing configuration will not be changed (the revert mechanism will be used) but your cfg file will be removed from /usr/local/nagios/etc/import. Just have a spare copy somewhere.

Tested on recent Nagios XI 5.8.4.

Comment: Thank you very much  @meolic , I have been trying for this for couple of days finally I got it, thank you thank you very much.

Comment: Good to know that this work also on old 4.4.6. Please, mark the answer as useful and accepted if it solves your problem.